# User data not returning anything from query call

Tags: javascript, graphql, express-graphql

I'm not sure which part I might be doing wrong. I was hoping to get some advice.

The query I am using in `GraphiQL` is:

```
query getUser($id:Int!) {
   user(id:$id) {
     id
    email
   }
}
```

For the backend I am using NodeJS. I am also declaring the user type as:

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        email: { type: GraphQLString }
    })
});
```

My root query is:

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: { id: { type: GraphQLInt } },
            resolve(parentValue, args) {
                const query = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$1`;
                const values = [ args.id ];
                dbQuery.query(query, values).then(({ rows }) => {
                    console.log(rows[0]);
                    return rows[0];
                });
            }
        }
    }
});

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({ query: RootQuery });
app.use(
    '/api/v1/graphql',
    graphqlHTTP({
        schema: schema,
        graphiql: true
    })
);
```

What I get in return is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": null
  }
}
```

I was hoping to know what I might be doing wrong that is resulting in null being returned instead of the data that I am querying from the database.

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be much more clear if you use with await

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: { id: { type: GraphQLInt } },
            resolve: async(parentValue, args) {
                const query = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$1`;
                const values = [ args.id ];
                const rows = await dbQuery.query(query, values);
                return rows[0];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When using a promise and returning anything inside the promise will only return the result to the promise that is executed. It will not be returning as a whole to the parent function.

You can also return the whole promise function like below

```
return dbQuery.query(query, values)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have tried doing both and the response I get back is null. The first approach instead returned user: { id: null, email: null} even though there is data being returned from the resolver.

Comment: It started to work. I'm not sure what I changed or what I may have done wrong but your answer was very helpful. Thank you so much :D